# Where is Redmine located by default?

Tags: debian, redmine

I'm very upset that I cant find the location I've installed Redmine in. There are several Redmine-dirs but not even one contains anything useful to install new plugins.

Where is Redmine located on Debian by default?

Answer (score 3):

to find out which files ship in a given (installed!) package, use the `--listfile` flag of the `dpkg` command:

this will show all files installed by `redmine`

```
dpkg -L redmine
```

for redmine plugins you may find this more useful:

```
dpkg -L redmine-plugin-recaptcha
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `/usr/share/redmine`.

Plugins are in `/usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins`, some configs are in `/etc/redmine`.